# Self property in parent class not working

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have a parent class with a method signature like this:

```
class MyParent {
  func doStuff(property: Self) {
    fatalError("Not Implemented")
  }
}
```

I then inherit form it like so:

```
final class MyInherited: MyParent {
  var arbitraryVal:String = "Hello"
  override func doStuff(property: MyInherited) {
    self.arbitraryVal = property.arbitraryVal
  }
}
```

However, it says that `doStuff` doesn't override any method from its superclass. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here and have a parent class required a method property be of type `Self`?

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code, to start with `final class MyInherited(): MyParent` this will give you compilation error, what you meant probably is `final class MyInherited: MyParent`, 2. You cant use Self as arguement type, compiler must have suggested you to use `MyParent` instead, `func doStuff(property: MyParent)` 3. `override func doStuff(property: MyInherited)` will not override `func doStuff(property: MyParent)` because though `MyInherited` inherits from `MyParent` , `func doStuff(property: MyParent)` and `doStuff(property: MyInherited)` method signatures arent same

Comment: Would be good to understand what you are actually trying to achieve with this inheritance structure? - Kinda looks like you might be touching on generics.

Comment: @Sandeep you are correct. I'll fix that little compile problem. The compiler does suggest not using `Self` in my method signature. Is it not possible to use `Self` in a non-protocol? And if not, how would I accomplish the same functionality. I'm trying to avoid type checking inside the overridden method.

Comment: @Wez I need a class with a method that expects a property of its own type that I plan to override. That overridden method should expect the property type to also be itself, not just any instance of its parent class. I am hoping to avoid type checking inside the method itself using a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Anything the superclass can do, the subclass must also be able to do. If MyParent.doStuff can accept a MyParent, then MyInherited.doStuff must also be able to accept a MyParent. Otherwise, if you passed this object to a function that accepted a MyParent, how would it type-check a later call to doStuff?

A subclass can restrict what it returns, but it cannot restrict what it accepts. So it's ok for the *output* of `doStuff` to be Self, but it's not possible for the *input* to be Self. The input has to be at least as permissive as its parent.

I would expect that you're receiving an error in MyParent, not just MyInherited. It should say:

> Covariant 'Self' can only appear as the type of a property, subscript or method result; did you mean 'MyParent'?

And this is correct. It's not possible to restrict a parameter to a smaller set of values. This isn't a Swift limitation. This is a limitation of any sound type system that includes inheritance.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll just end up needing to do a type check in the method to ensure the property matches the expected type I suppose.

Comment: Or redesign a bit to avoid the headaches of inheritance. You can use (final) classes with protocols to achieve similar things to what you're trying to do here. If what you're trying to do is fundamentally poorly defined, then nothing will fix that, but if it's well defined at compile time, then the type system should be able to help you enforce it. For example, the Equatable protocol has no trouble requiring that its parameters be Self. (But protocols with associated types introduce other issues, so worth considering carefully.)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this is related to similar code in another question of mine you answered, and using a protocol and final classes won't work with the other solution. I was originally using protocols and final classes, but had to change my protocol to a class for a different issue involving generic typing. Unfortunately, given the compiled nature of Swift, I'm in between two patterns that conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a protocol instead of a superclass

```
protocol MyParent {
    var arbitraryVal: String { get set }
    func doStuff(property: MyParent)
}
```

Comment: I am not able to use a protocol in my use case. It has to be a class.